# React functional component doesnt rerender when changing props passed as an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My functional Component doesn't rerender when i pass an array as it's props and change the values of the array.

https://codesandbox.io/s/5ym4vkrnnk

or

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const SomeFunctionalComponent = props => {
  return <span>{props.array[0]}</span>;
};

class App extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    array: [1, 2, 3]
  };
  increase = () => {
    var array = this.state.array;
    array[0] = array[0] + 1;
    this.setState({ array: array });
    console.log(this.state.array);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.increase}>Increase</button>
        <SomeFunctionalComponent array={this.state.array} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

My questions:

1. Why is that so?
2. How can i change that?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You are changing the value in the array, but the reference to the array stays the same. Since `react` sees the same object reference before and after you call `increase()`, it doesn't actually know that anything changed. You should try to use pure functions and immutability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Never Mutate the state directly**

you are mutating the state directly in your code so the changes are not getting reflected. Array becomes a reference to this.state.array, which causes the undesired mutation.

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const SomeFunctionalComponent = props => {
  return <span>{props.array[0]}</span>;
};

class App extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    array: [1, 2, 3]
  };
  increase = () => {
    var array = [...this.state.array];
    array[0] = array[0] + 1;
    this.setState({ array: array });
    console.log(this.state.array);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.increase}>Increase</button>
        <SomeFunctionalComponent array={this.state.array} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: you can add that `array` becomes a reference to `this.state.array`, which causes the undesired mutation

Comment: Thank you really much, seems like i lack some basic javascript knowledge... I thought when i write:var array = this.state.array; array[0] = array[0] + 1; I copy the value of this .state.array into another variable and then change it, instead of changing a reference?

Comment: As a side note, spread syntax creates a shallow copy. With this simple code it is OK, but if you change a nested property of the new array you mutate the original one.

Comment: @TimvonKänel that way you are doing is you are using the same array to make changes you need to create a completely new array before mutating it.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky thanks i have added it to the answer

Comment: @TimvonKänel, direct assign creates an object (arrays are objects) pointing the same object reference. If you change a property for the new one, you mutate the old one. Spread syntax and `Object.assign` creates shallow copies, means they copy just one level deep. So, if you mutate a nested property, you mutate the old one.